# Error validaciones ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jsp

Hola buen dia tengo una pregunta de como hacer que salte un error o una excepción en Ajax.

Mi problema es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando selecciono una ciudad que no tiene zonas, (registros en BD) requiero que salga un mensaje de error.

Sin embargo , actualmente el programa trae el `select` vació 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo hacer para que salte una excepción si la función si retorna datos, por lo cual la comparación en Ajax de `if(!datos)` no  funciona.

```
function obtenerZonas(ciudad) {
    $.ajax({
       url : "obtenerZonas.jsp?v_ciu=" + ciudad, /* se envia por GET */
       cache: false,
       dataType : 'html',
       success : function(datos) {
            if(!datos){
             $("#erroro").html("La ciudad Seleccionada No tiene Zonas. Error"+ ciudad );    
            }else{
            $('#zona').html(datos);
            }
       },
       error: function( ) {
             $("#errorz").html("Se presento un problema, Ciudad No. = " + ciudad);             
         } 
    });

}
```

La solución debería ser algo así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi problema es que el error salta en la nueva comparación por que el valor es null...

Pero cuando el problema se presente en microzona... no hay forma de validar el error, que debo hacer '?

Espero haberme hecho entender.. !!

Gracias!!

Comment: Creo que deberias hacer eso del lado del servidor me imagino que en tu JSP haces algun tipo de consulta, y ahí es donde podrias mandar una variable que tenga exito o error y ya en la respuesta del Ajax evaluas esa variable y dependiendo de lo que traiga es lo que vas a mostar.

Comment: Si entiendo lo que me dices, pero podrías darme un ejemplo de como recuperar la variable desde el JSP para validarlo en la función ajax? (y) @M.Gress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que entiendo en el `success` del `ajax`, la variable `datos` trea texto `HTML` donde esta el `select`. Algo así:

```
datos = '<select...><option..></option>...</select>'
```

Pero cuando la `ciudad` no tiene `zonas`, devuelve el `select` **vacío**. Algo así:

```
datos = '<select...></select>'
```

En este caso, la variable `datos` **no está vacía**, pero podemos ver que no tiene tags `option`.

Una solución, puede ser la de comprobar que en la variable `datos` no exista el texto `<option`, es decir, solo un `select` vacío.

Ejemplo:

```
if(datos.indexOf('<option') === -1) {
  $("#erroro").html("La ciudad Seleccionada No tiene Zonas. Error"+ ciudad );
}
$('#zona').html(datos);
```

### // Update

En [la imagen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8dBE.jpg) se puede ver que el contenedor del mensaje de error se llama `errorz` y si quieres que el `select` no aparezca, entonces puede hacer esto:

```
if(datos.indexOf('<option') === -1) {
  $("#errorz").html("La ciudad Seleccionada No tiene Zonas. Error"+ ciudad );
  $('#zona').html('');
} else {
  $('#errorz').html('');
  $('#zona').html(datos);
}
```

Comment: Edite la respuesta @marcos

Comment: Si , estas en lo correcto , mi intención es que el 'select' no aparezca en lugar de él , el mensaje de error.

Comment: El div, lo cambie de nombre cuando estaba probando , lamento la confusión. @Marcos

Comment: lamento haber editado tu respuesta, no sabia; Por otro lado el problema persiste,  he intentado por todas las formas posibles la comparación que planteas pero  sigue generándose el Select.

Comment: @AndresFelipeDiaz, He actualizado mi respuesta ya que había  cometido un error. Si `indexOf` es igual `-1`, quiere decir que no hay un `option`.

Comment: Si, lo note, gracias  como veras soy  nuevo en esto de  ajax!